# iText encoding problem

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, itext

I have encoding problem with iText (http://www.lowagie.com/iText/). I load data from database and insert it as html to pdf with iText, for some reason my non-english (Finnish ä,ö etc) characters don't show up correctly. Following example shows how insert text to html:

```
    text = "<p>" + data + "</p>";
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    htmlWorker.parse(isr);
```

UPDATE: If have to add that it's working in my Windows Vista system, but not in Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your default Locale set properly? Make sure that `Locale.getDefault()` is returning the value it should be. This could be different on windows and linux, if one of them hasn't been set up correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanx, locale was different on linux server, so it must be that what is causing this problem...

Comment: Just tested, I changed locale and locale changed, but I still get wrong characters

Comment: Hmm.. It was Firefox cache that chached wrong version restartring firefox helped and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [InputStreamReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) with appriopriate charset name.